# How to Map route to constructed Web API controllers for dependency injection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

All the example I see of WebAPI route look like this

```
        apiConfig.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "Echo Route", "WebSampleService/Echo/{message}",
            new { controller = "Echo" });
```

I understand that this assume I have a class called "EchoController" that derive from "ApiController" and that the framework will create an instance using reflexion automatically.

What I would like to do is to manually create an instance of EchoController using my dependency injection framework and tell the framework to route request to this instance.

If this is note possible, would it be possible to provide a factory method for the framework to call instead of using reflexion and calling the default constructor?

Comment: Why do you want to manually create an instance of your controller and route traffic to it? What problem are you trying to solve by doing that? Why don't you just use the DI support [built into the framework?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection) Why did you tag your question as `azure-web-app-service`?

Comment: apiConfig.DependencyResolver() is what I was looking for this way I can integrate  with my dependency injection framework.

Comment: If you have a common DI framework such as [AutoFac](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html), [SimpleInjector](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webapiintegration.html), or [Ninject](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.WebApi) they'll already have integrations built in.